# Областная олимпиада 2016. Борщ, картофель и салат

Tags: c++, олимпиада

В общем условие задания:

> Сегодня у пластунов праздник! Привезли вдвое больше продуктов на обед.
> Макс вместе с Маричкой вызвались помогать на кухне. Всего есть три
> разных блюда: борщ, картошка и салат. В пласте в Макса и Марички есть
> N друзей. i-й друг хочет съесть A грамм борща, B грамм картофеля и C
> грамм салата. Если друг Макса и Марички хочет съесть X грамм
> определенного блюда, а ему в тарелку положили Y грамм, то степень
> Недоверия к Максу и Марички у этого друга возрастет на |X-Y| единиц.
> Максу и Маричке приказали накладывать всем одинаковые порции
> определенного блюда. То есть каждому другу нужно наложить const A
> грамм борща, const B грамм картофеля и const C грамм салата. Помогите
> Максу и Маричке выбрать такие A, B, C чтобы суммарная степень
> недоверия всех друзей была как можно меньше.

***Входные данные:***
В первой строке записано целое число N - количество друзей. В следующих N строках записаны по три целых числа A, B, C - количество борща, картошки и салата, которую хочет получить i-й друг.

***Выходные данные:*** Одно целое число - суммарная степень недоверия всех друзей к Максу и Марички.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void sr(int a[], int& N, int j) {
    for(int i = j; i < N; i++) {
        if(i == N-1) break;
        else {
            a[i] = a[i+1];
        }
    }
    N -= 1;
}

void quicksort(int *mas, int first, int last)
{
    int mid, count;
    int f = first, l = last;
    mid = mas[(f+l) / 2]; 
    do
    {
        while (mas[f]<mid) f++;
        while (mas[l]>mid) l--;
    if (f<=l) 
    {
        count=mas[f];
        mas[f]=mas[l];
        mas[l]=count;
        f++;
        l--;
    }
    } while (f<l);
    if (first<l) quicksort(mas, first, l);
    if (f<last) quicksort(mas, f, last);
}


int main() {
    int N, i, l = 0, cnl = 0, bnl = 0, anl = 0, x;
    scanf("%i", &N);
    ...
    int a1 = 0, b1 = 0, c1 = 0, ch1 = 0, ch2 = 0, ch3 = 0;
    int final = 0;
    ...
    printf("\n%i", final);
```

}

Comment: На каком языке программирования это написано? Почему и зачем стоит тэг [C]? Почему сортировка реализована самостоятельно?

Comment: Мова программирования С, думал по коду будет понятно что и как. Тэг исправил, сорри.

Comment: `Сегодня у пластунов праздник! ` - кто такие `пластуны`? :) отличное задание! С национальным оттенком :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В общем, перейдем к реализации, задание работает за принципом медианы,
>   построение правильного ответа я реализовал в виде различных
>   вариантов для одного друга, двоих и больше трех, но в основном можно
>   оптимизировать и под одно условие это все.  Моя ошибка была в удалении
>   нулей из массива, так как по логике я считал что это только будет
>   увеличивать размеры недоверия.
>
> На самом же деле, приведу простой пример:
>
> У нас есть три друга:
>   0     0     0  - это порции еды для первого
>
> 50    50   50 - для второго
>
> 1020 1020 1020 - для третьего
>
> При расчете в случаи удаление нулей у нас получается, что: (50+1020)/3
>   = 356 => (356 + (356-50) + (1020-356) = 1 326!
>
> Без удаления, так как уже получается три друга, идет сортировка: 0 50
>   1020, берем медиану - 50 => 50 + 0 + 970 = 1020!
>
> PROFIT!
>
> Чисто в интересах задания не буду уже бросать готовый, выполненный код =)

Comment: А зачем вы делите на 3, сказано же "суммарная степень недоверия"

Comment: Потому что при двух друзьях мы физически не можем взять медиану с двух чисел, поэтому тут более рационально будет найти среднее арифметическое ну или же если не ошибаюсь даже взять макс. число тоже будет результат тот же. Ну а если вы все же о том почему на три, то это просто пример некорректного решения, деления на 3 в принципе быть не может, так как мы ищем среднее арифметическое только при двух друзьях. В других случаях, когда их 3+ мы сортируем массив и ищем медиану.

Comment: Но все же если не понятно объясню, так как думаю будут еще люди, у которых также будут на этом задании вопросы: Мы ищем оптимальное число, для A, B, C массиву(по столбцам), число, которое за формулой |X-Y|, где X это число, которое мы нашли и которое есть наиболее оптимальным, а Y - это количество грамм, которые хочет получить друг, мы будем добавлять к final. По такому принципу мы ищем для всех трех массивов, а переменная final в процессе сохраняет в себя суммарную степень недоверия, которая за нашим алгоритмом должна быть минимальная.